# How to rename duplicate .jpg file name in Mac

Tags: bash, macos, rename

My client give me data of images, but in my Mac the file names are with double jpg, like `3073416101453.jpg.jpg`

[image]

There is a total of 1200+ images, how to bulk remove one `.jpg` from file name in mac?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If none of the filenames contain any spaces, you can use the following bash syntax to remove the trailing extension:

```sh
filename='example.jpg.jpg'
echo ${filename%.*}
# example.jpg
```

Using [`find`](https://ss64.com/bash/find.html) to create a 'loop';

```sh
find /tmp/tst -type f -iname '*.jpg.jpg' | while read f; do mv $f "${f%.*}"; done
```

Example on MacOs;

```
$ touch example.jpg.jpg
$ touch blabla.jpg.jpg
$
$ ls
blabla.jpg.jpg  example.jpg.jpg
$
$ find /tmp/tst -type f -iname '*.jpg.jpg' | while read f; do mv $f "${f%.*}"; done
$
$ ls
blabla.jpg  example.jpg
$
$
```